# How to run a .load() from a another jquery script inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, jquery-plugins

I am completely new to jQuery.

I have script that will rotate scripts to load and run them by using document.write.

Here is it from a stackoverflow post but cant seem to remember now/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imageURLs = [
       "http://www.myserver.com/images/image1.png"
     , "http://www.myserver.com/images/image2.png"
     , "http://www.myserver.com/images/image3.png"
  ];
  function getImageTag() {
    var img = '<img src=\"';
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
    img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
    img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
    return img;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(getImageTag());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway; I am not a fan of document,write. Can this be done using jquery .load() like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#result" ).load( "" );
</script>
```

The image rotation script will run from the #result using:

```
<div id="result"/>
```

I am having such great problem figuring this out. Please help me out. Thanks to all.

## **Also want to do this with < script > tag**

Comment: You're escaping double quotes inside simple quotes, this is an error because the `\\` will actually appear in the output. What do you mean "script that will rotate scripts"? The whole thing runs only once.

Comment: You meant "script will rotate images"?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [`append()` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#result" ).append(getImageTag());
});
```

Results in

```
<div id='result'>
<img ... />
</div>
```

And your script is not so much rotating images as getting a random one.

Answer (score 0):

So, in jQuery, to display a random image from 'imageURLs' you could do the following:

```
var imageURLs = [
    "http://www.myserver.com/images/image1.png",
    "http://www.myserver.com/images/image2.png",
    "http://www.myserver.com/images/image3.png"
];

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
var $img = $("<img/>", {
    src: imageURLs[randomIndex],
    alt: 'Some Text'
});

$("#result").empty().append($img);
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/gr0Lz2Ly/3/)

And if you're after a function, see the below:

```
var getRandomImage = function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
    return $("<img/>", {
        src: imageURLs[randomIndex],
        alt: 'Some Text'
    });
};
$("#result").empty().append(getRandomImage);
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/gr0Lz2Ly/2/)